# Instance member cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have declared a variable itemGlobalArray in AppDelegate class like below

```
var itemGlobalArray = NSMutableArray()
```

and trying to use it in a view controller like below

```
if (AppDelegate.itemGlobalArray).count > 0 //Gives error here
        {
            let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BasketVC") as? BasketVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "cart Empty", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                switch action.style{
                case .default:
                    print("default")
                    
                case .cancel:
                    print("cancel")
                    
                case .destructive:
                    print("destructive")
                    
                    
                }}))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: add `static` before `var`

Answer (score 4):

You must declare it like static member, static members can be used without instance:

```
class AppDelegate {
    static var itemGlobalArray = NSMutableArray()

    //...
}
```

Than you can use it in your case:

```
if (AppDelegate.itemGlobalArray).count > 0 { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach is to use `UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate`